# Spring Boot application as a systemd service: log file

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, debian, systemd

I know it is possible to create a jar from Spring Boot application which can be used as a systemd service. I used [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-systemd-service) manual to create systemd service from my application on Debian Jessie OS. Eveyrthing works fine, but I can't find a way how to write logs to separate file insted of /var/syslog. As [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-systemd-service) says:

> Note that unlike when running as an init.d service, user that runs the
>   application, PID file and console log file behave differently under
>   systemd and must be configured using appropriate fields in ‘service’
>   script. Consult the service unit configuration man page for more
>   details.

it should be configured in *.service file, but I can't find any appropriate options. Has someone any experience in this question?

Comment: Top answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file

Answer (score 6):

Run the service with a `sh` process

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/var/myapp/myapp.jar >> /var/logs/myapp.log"
KillMode=control-group
```

See this discussion in influxdb github repo https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/4490

Comment: The correct command for me is  `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "java -jar /var/myapp/myapp.jar >> /var/logs/myapp.log"`

Comment: This works great except we can't control log file rolling / retention with spring boot properties such as logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history.  How do we keep that log file from growing out of control?

Comment: @KenKrueger I agree we can not benefit from logback rolling policy here. You can control log file size using systemd see https://superuser.com/a/1301058