# bash -e flag and '&&' list command

Tags: bash

How can explain this bash behavior ? Do not exit on '&&' statements ?

```
# bash -xe
bash-4.1# trap 'echo ERROR' ERR
+ trap 'echo ERROR' ERR
bash-4.1# false && true
+ false
bash-4.1# false && false
+ false
bash-4.1# false || true
+ false
+ true
bash-4.1# false || false
+ false
+ false
++ echo ERROR
ERROR
```

Answer (score 6):

Read carefully what `man bash` says about `set -e`:

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of  the  command  list  immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, **part of any  command  executed  in a `&&` or `||` list** except the command following the final `&&` or `||` [...]

Emphasis mine.

Detailed explanation: When running `false && false`, the first `false` makes the whole command fail because of short circuiting, and as it's not the last command in the construct, its exit status is ignored. In case of `false || false`, the first `false` makes the second `false` run which fails as well, but its exit status isn't ignored, as it's the last command in the construct.

Comment: That's exactly what my deleted answer contains (hope you can see it), but I just can't comprehend till now, how `false || false` is causing the `trap` from the parent shell for the same scenario, care to explain? Thanks!

Comment: @Inian: When running `false && false`, the first `false` makes the whole command fail because of short circuiting, and as it's not the last command in the construct, its exit status is ignored. In case of `false || false`, the first `false` makes the second `false` run which fails as well, but its exit status isn't ignored, as it's the last command in the construct.

Comment: Couldn't find this in any of the `man` pages, worth a `+10` just for this, `++`. Would be nice if you can add it to the answer for future reference, so that I can bookmark this. Thanks!

Comment: Thank for the clear explanation ! The exist status is ignored if it is not the last command in the list. Thanks again !