# Systemd logging to external file

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

I have the following Systemd service script to run a Spring boot application-

```
[Unit]
Description=Upstart for Security
After=network.target network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/security
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -classpath java -Dspring.profiles.active=stage -jar /home/ubuntu/security/security-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar > /home/ubuntu/security/security.log 2>&1
SuccessExitStatus=143
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=120s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**I save the script in the following location -**

```
 /etc/systemd/system
```

**I ran the following commands to run the systemd service script -**

```
1. sudo systemctl enable security.service -or- sudo systemctl daemon-reload
2. sudo systemctl status security.service 
3. sudo systemctl start security.service
```

**To check logs, I fire the command -**

```
journalctl -u security.service
```

and use `SHIFT+G` to scroll to eof

I am able to check the logs by the above steps, but I want them in an external file in location **/home/ubuntu/security** , as **security.log**
How can I achieve it? What change do I make in my systemd script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output of systemd service to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file)

Answer (score 12):

You can use syslog to accomplish this. instruct your systemd service to route stdout/stderr to syslog with an identifier and have syslog handle the writing to file.

```
[Service]
...
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=<your-svc-identifier>
```

Now add a config to syslog in `/etc/rsyslog.d/`

```
if $programname == '<your-svc-identifier>' then /var/log/<your-svc>.log
if $programname == '<your-svc-identifier>' then stop
```

Reload syslog

```
$ sudo systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding complexity through the [fan-in fan-out](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/unix-daemon-design-mistakes-to-avoid.html) `rsyslog`, it’s much neater to just have `systemd` write to your external file directly.

So, to use your example:

```
StandardOutput=append:/home/ubuntu/security/security.log
StandardError=append:/home/ubuntu/security/security.log
```

Note that `append:` is a feature introduced in `systemd` 240 (though backported to RHEL8 for instance).

Then, add a corresponding entry under `/etc/logrotate.d`.