# Can not redirect STDOUT to a file in Python daemon as Linux service

Tags: python, linux, stdout, daemon

In a Python daemon, I redirect the STDOUT and STDERR to some file with [two-fork mode](http://web.archive.org/web/20131017130434/http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/):

```
os.dup2(si.fileno(), sys.stdin.fileno())
os.dup2(so.fileno(), sys.stdout.fileno())
os.dup2(se.fileno(), sys.stderr.fileno())
```

Start the daemon and the STDOUT can redirect to my specified file in `/var/demo/stdout`.

But if I make the daemon module as an Linux service via Systemd, the service file like:

```
[Unit]
Description=demo
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/opt/demo/
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/anaconda3/bin/python3 -m scheduler.run start'
PIDFile=/var/run/demo.pid
SyslogIdentifier=Demo
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The STDOUT seems does not redirect to the file `/var/demo/stdout`.
Service type set to **forking** and **ExecStart** command has been tested and it can worked as expected.

So the only question is why the STDOUT can not redirect to a normal file if the Python module runs as an Linux service.

Comment: I checked the redirect normal file and find it already opened in the Python daemon process(PID is 14384):`#fuser stdout 
/var/log/demo/stdout: 14384`
But there is nothing sent to the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect output of systemd service to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file)