# Dotnet app started as daemon doesn't working properly

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, daemon

I developed a simple application using `NetCore`, the app write the content on a file every time is executed, this is the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SimpleApp
{
   class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true))
          {
              writer.WriteLine("Hello World");
          }
       }
   }
}
```

so if I start the application in this way: `dotnet SimpleApp.dll` I get a `log.txt` file with `Hello World` in it.

Now, I'm trying to create a linux daemon, I have no experience in that, so I wrote what I learned on Internet, I created a service cakked `console.service` which contains this structure:

```
[Unit]
Description = Hello World Daemon

[Service]
ExecStart = /usr/bin/dotnet /home/my username/Desktop/publish/SimpleApp.dll
Restart = on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

So essentially I have a description, and I setted in `ExecStart` the path of my `dotnet` installation and the path of the application.

Later I have an `Install` that if understood well tell to the `systemctl` that the service can run for each user, right?

Later, I copied the service in the `system` folder:

```
sudo cp console.service /lib/systemd/system
```

and I enabled it:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
sudo systemctl enable console.service
```

so, I executed the service:

```
sudo systemctl start console.service
```

and when I print the status:

```
systemctl status console.service
```

will is displayed this:

[image]

the problem's that inside the folder `publish` (the path of the application specified in ExecStart) I doesn't have any log.txt at this time.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only specified a relative path for the file, it will be created in the working directory of the service.

You can either change `"log.txt"` to a full path or set the working directory in the .service file:

```
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/you/want/the/file/to/be/in
…
```

Comment: Thanks, just a little question: suppose that I want display the Console.WriteLine as a "terminal log", is possible to do this? Should I write some configuration in the service file or I should edit my c# console? Thanks for the help!

Comment: you could do it in systemd+syslog: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file

Comment: or use any .net logging library (e.g. serilog with a rolling log file sink) (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging acts as abstraction layer if you use libraries or want to create independent components)

Comment: wait, I mean the output generated by console.writeline not the log.txt