# Systemd unit configuration with shell expansion

Tags: linux, bash, systemd

I'm finally trying to convert my old init.d management script to systemd, and have run into a snag that I hope someone else has found a solution to.

My application expects an argument for the name of the file it saves logging information to, and my init script generates that name at startup with this line:

```
LOGFILE=`/bin/date "+$MUDDIR/lib/log/runlog.%y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
```

How would I go about having such a construct get run so the value is available for use in ExecStart?

Can I do something as simple as

```
ExecStartPre=LOGFILE=`/bin/date "+${MUDDIR}/lib/log/runlog.%y%m%d-%H%M%S"`
```

or would it throw a fit at trying to spawn a shell there?  If it runs the command as a subshell, the value would be thrown away.

Also, if I specify multiple ExecStartPre lines, will they be executed in order?

Thanks for any hints.  The documentation is a bit light on details in some places, and I'm just trying to preserve my original functionality without being cheesy and just having it call my old script.

Comment: See [Unix.SE: Dynamic logic in systemd service file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223973/dynamic-logic-in-systemd-service-file)

Comment: See [Unix.SE: Dynamic variables in systemd service unit files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323914/dynamic-variables-in-systemd-service-unit-files)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend letting systemd manage logging via its journal. Don't create a log file at all. Just have the application write to stdout/stderr. That way the logs will get stored alongside all the other applications' logs, they'll be searchable via `journalctl`, they'll show up in `systemctl status <app>`, they'll be rotated automatically, etc.

If the application absolutely requires a `$LOGFILE` environment variable you could use:

```
Environment=LOGFILE=/dev/stdout
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with OP's answer about letting `journalctl` handle logging. Rather than calling `/dev/stdout` in `Environment` attribute, use the following:

```
[Service]
...
...
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

This will put your logs into the system log, such as `/var/log/messages` and in `journalctl`. You can access the log using the `service name`:

```
journalctl -u myawesomeservice.service
```

As it seems, [on newer (>238) systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/7198), you can set path to the log file.

```
StandardOutput=file:/path/to/logfile.log
StandardError=file:/path/to/logfile.err
```

Here is [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file/37595720) that provides much more info.