# Redirecting output of bluez btmgmt to file from systemd service

Tags: bluez

I try to have separate ssp modes during connection using Bluetooth btmgmt utility. Basic idea is scan current device OUI and select ssp on/off modes. But I can't get any answer from neither **btmgmt con** or **btmgmt info** commands when I put them into .service files. My system is Arch Linux arm 32-bit and bluez stack version is 5.55-1. I tried

```
[Unit]
Description=check Bluetooth address

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/btmgmt info >> /usr/local/lib/mac 2>&1'
```

without any success: it just puts nothing in output file. Some tricks like add

```
User=root
Group=root
```

or substitute ExecStart with

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo -e "$(btmgmt con)" >> /usr/local/lib/mac 2>&1
```

did nothing. I tried changed thing by putting btmgmt stuff in different bash script instead of start them right from service file, i.e.

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/lib/test1
```

to no avail. I'm confused completely, because of:

1. It doesn't seem to be general btmgmt thing problem, because I can set ssp mode from service files
   in very simple manner, just using

   ExecStart=btmgmt off

or

```
ExecStart=btmgmt off
```

even without full path.

2. It doesn't seem to be redirecting command error as well, because if I add

   ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/fdisk -l > /usr/local/lib/mac 2>&1'

it does work without any problem and I see fdisk info in file (I use fdisk because it requires elevated rights same as btmgmt one).
Moreover, **btmgmt info** works in the same way, i.e. shows nothing in out file. It makes me think something is wrong in output of btmgmt. I talk about output because input parameters work fine in btmgmt ssp on/of commands and **journalctl** and **systemct** don't show any errors in btmgmt con/info cases, so it seems to like output generating successfully but then sending somewhere to outer space, but I'm not sure completely.
Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Does this help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830129/7721752

Comment: Yes, I tried `StandardOutput=file:/usr/local/lib/mac` and it didn't help me, I just forgot to mention that.

Comment: Moreover, I think it's not redirecting problem at all, because I did a couple of extra checks and found out, that output of commands **btmgmt --help btmgmt --version** is redirected successfully, same for **btmgmt help** as well. But any other command including **btmgmt version** doesn't produce any output (at all maybe?) So its really looks like something screwed up inside **btmgmt** itself.

Comment: I can imagine that `btmgmt` was never intended to be used in this manner. A better approach might be to have a script that talks directly to the socket as detailed in the docs  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/mgmt-api.txt

Comment: Ubuntu 23.10 has the same issue now. It took me more than a day to find something useful and a workaround in my situation. https://github.com/jglathe/linux_ms_dev_kit/issues/6 Should be fixed, this is annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I make a statement: `btmgmt` is quite intended to be used for output at any manner, but they tried make a zillion variants of output which directed to exact result it should be: bug is buried somewhere deep inside of **bt_shell_printf** and **struct data**. I'm not ready run through all that disgusting documented code (I mean total absence of comments or more-or-less satisfactory mans), so I ended up with a liitte bit hacked version of utility downgraded to simple `fprintf` in output, leaving only commands I need: **con, ssp, power** and simplified until only current setting printing **info**. Everything works fine, and I can use that kind of `btmgmt` not with `systemd` only, but even with `udev` rules (indirectly, of course)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem, and managed to fix it after hours and hours of trying.

I don't know why in the world this happens to be so hard with `btmgmt` but here's the fix:

```
[Unit]
After=bluetooth.service
Description=Bluetooth service

[Service]
ExecStart=<your-process>
Group=root
StandardInput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty2
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
Type=simple
User=root
```

Basically, by occupying a TTY, `btmgmt` will think it's running in an interactive terminal, and will output as usual.

Hope this saves anyone the hell I've been through!