# Read debug output from journalctl from inside C++ code

Tags: c++, stdout, embedded-linux, systemd

`enter code here`I have a C++ application running on an Embedded Linux device which uses systemd.

If I wish to stream the debug output of my services / processes, I SSH into the device and execute command `journalctl -u <my_systemd_service>.service -f` from the terminal, where `<my_systemd_service>` is my actual service name.

Now the issue is that during production, I'd like to have SSH disabled for security reasons. However, I would still like to be retrieve the debug output sometimes, triggered by sending an MQTT command to the device as the device is connected to an MQTT broker.

Is there a way to get my debug output from within the C++ code itself when the MQTT command is received?

I don't suppose using `system()` would be ideal. For example `system("journalctl -u <my_systemd_service>.service -f")` ? Of course this would also need to run in a separate thread if so. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can direct service stdout/stderr to a file then read it using `std::fstream` whenever you need. You might want to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43830129/11277878

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have so much debug output and a little bit worried about continuously writing to a file 24/7. I guess writing to a file in RAMdisk would be better than writing to a file in Flash anyways?

Comment: You are right. I'm not a logging expert but in addition to my answer, I can also suggest classifying output messages with a console interface. You can enumerate output types as error, info, warning etc. then maybe log only panicky ones to a file so you it will consume less space. Also you can locate your log file under /tmp so it will be removed on next boot.