# How to redirect printf log to a specific file for a daemon process in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, daemon, systemctl

I have demon process ex. sample.  I have service file which will trigger main process launch file. When system boots up based on this file it will create `/var/log/sample.out` and `/var/log/sample.err` file for logging.

I need to redirect printf log into this `sample.out` file.
Is there way I can do this?

I added below statement to do the same but its not showing any logs in `/var/log/sample.out` or `/var/log/sample.err`.

```
${binary} > ${logs}.out 2> ${logs}.err
```

**sample.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Demon starteed \n");
}
```

**sample.service**

```
[Unit]
Description="sample service"

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/sample.service.start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**sample.service.start**

```
service=sample
binary=/usr/bin/${service}
logs=/var/log/${service}
${binary} > ${logs}.out 2> ${logs}.err
```

Comment: `I need to` Why do you *need* to? Wouldn't you want to use your system logging features? And, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48052152/9072753 should answer your question.

Comment: @KamilCuk this I need to do for debug purpose not for production

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add arbitrary shell commands to a systemd service file. Read the documentation of systemd, in particular [the part about executing binaries](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for how to modify the behavior of a program. To redirect standard output and error messages use:

```
StandardOutput=/var/log/sample.out
StandardError=/var/log/sample.err
```