# Why can't I start my camel3 fat-jar route as systemd service on raspberry pi?

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, systemd, fatjar, apache-camel-3

I have created a fat-jar for my apache camel 3 route. I put that on my raspberry pi (bullseye) in /opt/myhome and could start it successfully with java 17 (also works with sudo):

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/myhome/myhome-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Then I have added `/lib/systemd/system/myhome.service` as:

```
[Unit]
Description=My home automation with apache camel 3.
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/myhome/myhome-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar > /var/log/myhome.log 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

Then I did:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable myhome.service
sudo systemctl start myhome.service
```

After starting and waiting for some seconds I executed

```
systemctl status myhome.service
```

Which displays me

```
● myhome.service - My home automation with apache camel 3.
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myhome.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2022-10-07 18:28:52 CEST; 1h 18min ago
Process: 18159 ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/myhome/myhome-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar > /var/>
Main PID: 18159 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CPU: 10.174s

systemd[1]: Started My home automation with apache camel 3..
java[18159]: WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
java[18159]: Apache Camel Runner takes the following options
java[18159]:   -h or -help = Displays the help screen
java[18159]:   -r or -routers <routerBuilderClasses> = Sets the router builder classes which will be loaded while starting the camel context
java[18159]:   -d or -duration <duration> = Sets the time duration (seconds) that the application will run for before terminating.
java[18159]:   -dm or -durationMaxMessages <durationMaxMessages> = Sets the duration of maximum number of messages that the application will process before terminating.
java[18159]:   -di or -durationIdle <durationIdle> = Sets the idle time duration (seconds) duration that the application can be idle before terminating.
java[18159]:   -t or -trace = Enables tracing
java[18159]:   -ts or -traceStandby = Enables tracing standby
java[18159]:   -e or -exitcode <exitcode> = Sets the exit code if duration was hit
java[18159]:   -pl or -propertiesLocation <propertiesLocation> = Sets location(s) to load properties, such as from classpath or file system.
systemd[1]: myhome.service: Succeeded.
systemd[1]: myhome.service: Consumed 10.174s CPU time.
```

So this means the process was started, but then not the same as when starting the jar manually happens, but a help message seems to appear.

So the question is, why did the jar behaves differently as when started manually?

I also tested to change the code in `myhome.service` to:

```
/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/myhome/myhome-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -e 10 -d 60 -r de.powerstat.camel.homeautomation.HomeautomationRouteBuilder > /var/log/myhome.log 2>&1
```

Which results in the same as above. So no different exit code because of a timeout, or a not found route class.

What point did I miss here?

**Update 1:**

Completed the `systemctl status` output. Looks like this comes from `org.apache.camel.main.MainCommandLineSupport`

So the question is still why this shows up when starting in systemd context and not when starting within the bash?

Within my jar file the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` looks like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: PowerStat
Build-Jdk: 17.0.2
Main-Class: de.powerstat.camel.homeautomation.MainApp
```

while the MainApp class is defined as follows:

```
public class HomeautomationRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about systemd are for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: For me this is a programing question, because Camel3 behaves differently in the normal and the systemd environment.

Comment: The issue isn't happening when programming, compiling, etc and the linux people do know how to run a java program without being java programmers because they know systemd. Regarding your fix, `>` redirection is a shell feature and I guess there is no shell interpreting happening in `ExecStart`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585758/how-to-redirect-output-of-systemd-service-to-a-file has a solution with running it with `sh -c` which adds a shell interpreter into the mix (That question is also wrong here :D)

Comment: Infrastructue as code (Iac) would make it possible ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out that "> /var/log/myhome.log 2>&1" will be passed as three parameters to `args`. Because these parameters are not recognized results in the shown help message.